# AngularJS browser cache route pages disable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I have a website using AngularJS and Bootstrap. The problem is with the cache in the client browser. I post something...the client gets old stuff from cache. I am using angular-ui-router-0.3.1 for routing.

I am using `cache: false` in `$stateProvider` but nothing.

Here is the index which i use to route HTML pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>    
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
...
</head>
<body>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html'
    })
    .state('presentation', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/presentation',
        templateUrl: 'pages/presentation.html'
    })
    .state('about', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html'
    })
    ...
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
```

The big problem is for example, when I update the presentation page the client doesn't get the updates.

What should I do to force the route page to load even if it's stored in cache??? Or how to tell the client browser, do not cache the route pages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**:  Create a variable in your config to be used as a querystring, such as:

```
var version = 1.01;
```

Then change all your `templateUrl` like so:

```
templateUrl: 'pages/main.html?v=' + version
```

Each time you push a new version to production, update your `version` variable.  This should force the browser to reload the templates since it has no way of knowing what the new querystring represents.

**Step 2**:  If you also want to force a reload of the main page, here are the minimum requirements to satisfy all browsers:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: i have noticed something...if in the cache is the version 1.9 and on the server is version 1.13 it loads the cache version 1.9.  Why???

Comment: You need to make sure you use the `meta` tags so the main page reloads and the browser sees the latest version.  You may have to hard refresh it once first if you're adding the `meta` tags for the first time.